# Sign-in flow with Jetpack Navigation and RxJava + Dagger2

Tags: android, architecture, rx-java2, dagger-2, android-jetpack

**TL;DR**

Considering the new recommendations regarding Launcher Screen and start destination navigation, how should we elegantly integrate the sign-in logic in an Android app, using Jetpack Navigation and RxJava?

---

Following the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-principles), my app should have a fixed start/exit screen. Let's call this the HomeScreen.

Considering the access to this screen is only for signed-in users (like all the other screens, except the `LoginFragment`), where and how should I put the logic to check "is my user signed-in? No, navigate to `LoginFragment`"?

My application is divided in layers (onion architecture). I have a `SessionManager` POJO injected in my `Remote layer`, holding the token and other session related information used in the `Remote layer`.
I also have a UserRepository, used in my LoginUser use case, which will populate / update the `SessionManager`.

I don't want every use case or every presenter to check if the user is logged-in, as this is not their concern (right?). When and how should I check that my user is logged-in?
In the `MainActivity` holding the nav component? How can I change navigation properly as I'm using RxJava (so response to check is async)?

**Questions**

Should I do that in a SplashScreen / Launcher? Should that Launcher be a separate activity (conflict with the new [Single Activity recommendation](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html?m=1)), or should it be part of my navigation? Should I do the checks in my Application OnCreate, and delay the launch of my MainActivity? Should each presenter compose use cases, calling first the "am i logged in?" then the "do stuff"?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that there are plenty of solutions to this. Here's my two cents.

Inside your Application class, use a [subcomponent](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html) to represent the login state of the app. This, let's say, `userComponent` adds User-scoped bindings for everything that requires the user account, such as username, credentials, authenticated API client. Then make sure all fragments (except LoginFragment) inject using this component. This could be your Application class:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    private lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent
    private var userComponent: UserComponent? = null
    ...
}
```

On initial launch, your MainActivity will check the login state (`userComponent == null`) and navigate to LoginFragment if necessary. A successful authentication should then build the `userComponent` and seed it with user details. When then navigating to any other fragment, it has access to this subcomponent and all its bindings. To later sign out, set `userComponent = null` and navigate away from your user fragments.

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    ...
    fun signIn(account: Account) {
        userComponent = appComponent.userComponent().account(account).build()
    }

    fun signOut() {
        userComponent = null
    }
}
```

To skip login on second app start, attempt to sign in the user (build the `userComponent`) in the Application's `onCreate`. Your single MainActivity will then immediately navigate to, e.g., your HomeFragment.

**For [dagger.android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) users:** Get your `fragmentInjector` from your `userComponent` so that `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)` gets you access to User-scoped bindings.

```
class MyApplication : Application(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {
    private var fragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>? = null
    ...
    fun signIn(account: Account) {
        userComponent = appComponent.userComponent().account(account).build()
        fragmentInjector = userComponent.fragmentInjector()
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector() = fragmentInjector!!
    ...
}
```

I hope this answer is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the build of the component for the 2nd launch, what if the build process is asynchronous? MainActivity would be loaded before the loading process is complete, right?

Comment: This case indeed assumes a synchronous call. All that the user component needs though is some sort of ID of the previously selected user. Could be as little as a string, or here, the `Account` from Android's `AccountManager`. Any sort of fetching fresh auth tokens, or validating existing ones take place within the user scope. When this leads to a case where the user needs to re-enter his credentials or otherwise cannot recover, the app could auto-logout shortly after launch.

Comment: In my case, this "sort of ID" is retrieved from a Repository using RxJava, so it's definitely asynchronous. What would be the more elegant way of dealing with the flow, avoiding blinking screens? Using a splashscreen and a "loading" state in the UserComponent?

Comment: Loading a single identifier from shared preferences synchronously has little performance impact compared to other things many application tend to do at start. So your option here would be to not utilize the database for this simple step.

Comment: It's more a question of design and separation of concerns than a performance issue: all access to repositories are asynchronous :)